# How to click a button of the page to change the source of the frame of Windows?

Tags: wpf, frame

I have a WPF project, I add a frame in the Windows,the source of the frame is the page. I want to achieve clicking a button in the page to change the page of the frame.

```
<Window x:Class="MagicArm.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MagicArm"
    Title="MainWindow">
   <Frame Name="FrameContent"Source="PageStart.xaml"></Frame>
</Window>
```

PageStart:

```
<Page x:Class="MagicArm.PageStart"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
  xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
  mc:Ignorable="d" 
  Height="452" Width="800"
  Title="PageStart">
<Canvas>
 <button name=""> </button>
</Canvas>
```

Comment: what you tried ? where you are stuck ? can you be a little bit more specific ?

Comment: <Window > <Frame Name=""  Source="Page.xaml"></Frame></Window>
I have a button in the page ,i want to change the source of the frame when i click the button.how can i do?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

EDIT: A functional solution can look like:

MainWindow XAML:

```
<StackPanel>
    <Frame Name="frmMainContent" Height="260"
         DataContext="MyPageInformation"
         Source="{Binding}"
         NavigationUIVisibility="Hidden">           
    </Frame>

</StackPanel>
```

MainWindow cs:

```
 frmMainContent.Source = new Uri("test1.xaml", UriKind.Relative); // initialize frame with the "test1" view
```

test1 XAML:

```
<Grid>
    <Button Click="ButtonBase_OnClick" Background="Red" Height="30" Width="100">Go to page 2</Button>
</Grid>
```

test1 cs:

```
private void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        NavigationService ns = NavigationService.GetNavigationService(this);
        ns.Navigate(new Uri("test2.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
    }
```

test2 XAML:

```
  <Grid>
        <Button Click="ButtonBase_OnClick" Width="100" Height="30" Background="RoyalBlue"> Go to page 1</Button>
    </Grid>
```

test2 cs:

```
 NavigationService ns = NavigationService.GetNavigationService(this);
            ns.Navigate(new Uri("test1.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
```

This is a working solution using NavigationService.

Comment: The button is in the page and the page is the source of the frame,it  is not in the window.Window is the parent form of the page.

Comment: In this case i think you need EventPublisher to notify the parent view, reference here : http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/23314.using-the-event-aggregator-pattern-to-communicate-between-view-models.aspx

Comment: Thank you.It's a good solution.
If I want to click the button of the page to close the window ,how can i do?

Comment: please create another question with more details. You want the close button inside the frame to be functional ? or ?