# Main Frame Listening to Page Button Click Event

Tags: c#, wpf, master-pages

I have a Main Window, which is the frame that displays different pages in my project, I would like when a button on a page is clicked, to change the page in the frame.

The problem is I can't seem to get the Frame to contain the event handler for when the button is clicked, it seems local to the page itself. Is there a way for the Frame to see when the page's button is clicked and change the page accordingly?

```
Main.Content = new Page.Intro();
```

However when the button `Next` is clicked within `Page.Intro()` I want within the `Main Window Class` to the display

```
Main.Content = new Page.Home(userinformation);
```

I tried to follow [How to click a button of the page to change the source of the frame of Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29297986/how-to-click-a-button-of-the-page-to-change-the-source-of-the-frame-of-windows) which is similar to what I'm trying to achieve, although my pages have parameters I need to pass so I can't call `MainContent.Source = new Uri("Home.xaml", UriKind.Relative);`as there is no where to pass `userinformation`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> as there is no where to pass userinformation

`Navigate` method not only takes a `Uri`, it has [an overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.navigation.navigationservice.navigate?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Windows_Navigation_NavigationService_Navigate_System_Object_) that takes an object as parameter. So this works for you

```
//button click in Page.Intro
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.NavigationService?.Navigate(new Page.Home(userinformation));
}
```

Comment: Thankyou so much! Perfect solution to something I've been struggling with for weeks.

Comment: @Explorex you are welcome. The question mark is used to protect against null reference, I mention this as it may look strange to you.