# Page loaded in frame is not styled

Tags: c#, wpf, windows

I can't for the life of me figure out how to make a multiple page application in wpf. My issue is that when I load a page into the frame it does not use the style of the page

xaml

```
<Frame x:Name="Main" Margin="0,82,0,0"</Frame>
```

c# code

```
private void SettingsButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {
    Main.DataContext = new settingsPage();
    Main.Content = new settingsPage();

    SettingsButton.Content = Main.DataContext.ToString();

  }
```

Hopefully someone knows what is going on here and can help :)
Thanks

Comment: Besides that you should use the `Frame.Navigate` method, you are obviously creating two instances of your settingsPage class. That makes no sense. Start reading here: [Navigation Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/app-development/navigation-overview).

Comment: Is this just a regular app or a "wizard" style one where the user is taken through a series of steps they might wish to go back and forth through? If the former i recommend viewmodel first navigation and usercontrols rather than pages. Frames come with a lot of baggage. https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/52485.wpf-tips-and-tricks-using-contentcontrol-instead-of-frame-and-page-for-navigation.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Here you can find a fully working example:
[Usage of Frame control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29297986/how-to-click-a-button-of-the-page-to-change-the-source-of-the-frame-of-windows/29299811#29299811)

The thing is that you just need to switch the source of the frame by using the **NavigationService**. That should do the trick with your styles.